# Guidewire :: Policyperiod entity

Tags: policy, billing, guidewire

Why for policy period entity ,attribute type = effdated in policy center whereas it’s retireable in billing center ?

Tried searching in documents but was unable to conclude.could someone please help me understanding the difference

Answer (score 3):

**PolicyPeriod** is not an `effdated` entity in PolicyCenter and this is a common misconception. PolicyPeriod is an `effdatedbranch` entity. An `effdatedbranch` entity is a `retireable` entity. Such entities are used to define the entity type of the root of a tree that contains `effdated` entities. So PolicyPeriod itself is not effdated but it is the root of all other `effdated` entities like **PolicyLine**, **PolicyDriver**, **Cost**, etc.

So the hierarchy of entities in PC is like

```
Policy [effdatedcontainer] -> PolicyPeriod [effdatedbranch] -> All [effdated] entities
```

PolicyCenter necessitates `effdated` entities to facilitate an accurate point-in-time reconstruction of all policy attributes during Policy Periods. The reason behind introducing `effdated` is to enable the revisioning of entities according to effective and end dates. Consequently, every modification to a policy (via jobs) results in the creation of a new policy period row. This allows for the retrieval of a specific segment of the policy based on a `slice date`. Version changes to a policy hold paramount significance in PolicyCenter, particularly in the context of rate calculation.

On the contrary, BillingCenter does not necessitate the storage of multiple versions of a policy. Only the bound or promoted version is transmitted to BillingCenter along with a detailed breakdown of charges and costs, which BC then slices and incorporates into invoices. The majority of entities are categorized as `retireable` since there is no requirement to version them based on effective and end dates. This entity type is recommended for most common use cases, even when creating a custom entity.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that a PolicyPeriod in BillingCenter and PolicyCenter represent two different concepts.

- In PolicyCenter, a PolicyPeriod is a slice of a term.
- In BillingCenter, a PolicyPeriod represents a term which better maps to PolicyTerm in PolicyCenter.